# Cleanly assign nested this.props const in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In `render()` im passing many variables around. Best practises seem to point to doing things like this before calling a `return <div>...etc</div`:

```
const {
        products: mainProducts,
        parent,
        getProductsByOffset,
        offset,
        count,
        formOnChange,
        isGettingMissingProducts
    } = this.props
```

thats all well and good, but i have one particular object i need to fetch thats nested deep. Instead of getting the object/s doing:

```
        const assignProducts = this.props.parent.props.input.values
```

how would I go about extracting it nicely. I assume its possible and in best practise to be able to do this inline with how I did `products: mainProducts`

Answer (score 0):

I do think that your `const assignProducts = this.props.parent.props.input.values` looks better than any alternative, but if you want to continue destructuring to extract that nested property, you can use the following syntax:

```
const {
  products: mainProducts,
  parent,     // if you only need the `assignProducts`, remove this line
  parent: { props: { input: { values: assignProducts }}},
  getProductsByOffset,
  offset,
  count,
  formOnChange,
  isGettingMissingProducts
} = this.props
```

Note that you can extract both the `parent` property (if you need it) *and* extract a property inside `parent` at once. But that looks a bit uglier than your original code IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of best practices, deeply nested objects are considered brittle because code that depends on that deep nesting structure will break if that nesting structure changes anywhere.

There are many techniques for avoiding deeply nested objects. One is to "normalize" your data into a set of flat or nearly-flat lists. See ["Normalizing State Shape"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape) in the Redux docs.

If you must work with nested data, assuming the data is coming from your Redux state, you can still decouple the nested structure from your rendering code, by creating a *selector* function which you call in `mapStateToProps()`. Typically you put the selector's code adjacent to the reducer (possibly in the same file as the reducer). When you change the redux state shape by changing the reducer, you then update the selector to reflect the new shape. Your display component code and your mapStateToProps are shielded from these changes and will continue to work with no code changes.

Your selector would look like this:

```
export const Selectors = {
    getInputValues: state => state.parent.props.input.values
}
```

Then your  `mapStateToProps()` would look like this:

```
import { Selectors } from '../reducer'; // wherever your reducer is
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {assignProducts: Selectors.getInputValues(state)}
}
```